# How to display GLSL shaders on a png

Tags: glsl, webgl

I have a GLSL shader in .fs format, and am trying to figure out how to display it onto a white png to then get the texture of the shader.

I've tried running it in ShaderToy, which didn't work as they weren't compatible, also tried just running it with WebGL in html, but also to no avail.

Comment: Are you referring to applying a filter to an image? What did you actually try? What isn't working?